# ms-access query pattern matching

Tags: ms-access, pattern-matching

I have strings like

```
'Day 2', 
'Day 21', 
'Post-Surgery Visit -Observational Cohort', 
'Day 10 -Observational Cohort'
```

How can I write an Access query to get strings that are like 'Day' and followed by only digits. In my example, it should return only 'Day 2', 'Day 21'. And then in the select query I want to extract the numbers 2 from 'Day 2' and 21 from 'Day 21'. How to accomplish this? It would be great if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT [FolderName], val(mid([FolderName],5)) As NumberPart FROM [tbl]
WHERE [FolderName] LIKE 'Day 2*'
```

Like expression 'Day 2*' filters records with 'Day 2', 'Day 21'.
And expression 'val(mid([FolderName],5))' will cut out 'Day ' and evaluate the rest of the string to number.

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.

Comment: @Robert , i've edited answer. Is it ok now?